# App Engine OAuth provider CORS

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, oauth, cors

I've setup a small App Engine web application that provides an API for a certain task. My goal is to connect to this using a static web front-end and several native client applications. For authentication I'm using the built-in OAuth provider.

Consumer tokens for the clients have been created using the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

A ruby script used for API testing is successfully authenticating and able to request data from OAuth protected API urls.

However trying to access the `/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken` using javascript from a different host results in a CORS security exception:

> Origin http://exampledomain.nl is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

The domain the html/javascript is hosted on has been specified in the `JavaScript origins` field of the consumer in the API Console. I've verified it matches the domain the CORS error complains about exactly.

- Is App Engine OAuth ignoring the `JavaScript origins` or am I missing something here?
- Or is it possible to authenticate a (static) client side javascript application to app engine OAuth in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case seems like a good fit for [Google Cloud Endpoints](http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com/). The Google API client libraries, which work directly with Endpoints, will handle the details of minting tokens for your applications. Endpoints also natively supports CORS.

Comment: I see several problems with this: 1. I've requested access but not heard anything back for a few weeks already. 2. The app is currently written in Go, which I believe is not supported yet in endpoints? I would consider rewriting in python if that is the only way to use oauth2.

Comment: Endpoints TT is in open signup. Join the forum linked on that page to get access to the documentation, there aren't any other requirements. You're correct that Go is not currently supported. Endpoints is currently a good fit unless you are OK with Java or Python.

Comment: Ah, I vaguely remember using a google docs form to request access, but  can't seem to find that anymore. Thanks for the clarification on the open signup. I'll probably start deploying a python version to experiment with oauth2.